# How to switch off Vim's text search mode?

Tags: vim

I just search a text by `/text` but cannot close the mode to get away the highlight on the words. What command works in that way.

Comment: `:noh` will switch the highlighting off.  You can map it to something like `<leader><leader>` to quickly get rid of it.

Comment: I end up typing `/xx` or something quick and stupid that it won't find lol. `:noh` is faster if you need a lot of x's. I like the idea of mapping a key to `:noh`.

Comment: @mbratch `/xx` may clear the hl, but it will be saved in register. should be careful to do something like `:s//bar/g`.

Comment: @Kent, yeah good advice. I'll probably switch over to the key map you suggested anyway, now that I'm aware of it. I guess I was always too lazy or in a hurry to look up the proper command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`:noh`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/pattern.html#%3anohlsearch) (`:nohlsearch`) will clear the highlighting from the search result.

I have

```
nnoremap <silent> <F2>  :noh<cr>
```

in my vimrc, so that I can just press <kbd>F2</kbd> to clear the highlighting.

if you want to disable highlighting on search, you could just [`set nohlsearch`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#%27hlsearch%27).

Comment: As well as having a mapping for `:nohl`, I use the plugin [“unimpaired.vim”](https://github.com/tpope/vim-unimpaired), which lets me press `coh` to easily “change option hlsearch” (toggle highlighting for all future searches).

Answer (score 0):

Type in:

`:nohl`

This removes the previous search highlighting.

Answer (score 0):

I have been using this in `my.vimrc` so hitting enter removes the highlighting.

```
nnoremap <CR> :noh<CR><CR>
```